# Java : Skip Unicode characters while reading a file

Tags: java, unicode

I am reading a text file using the below code,

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(<file.txt>))) {
   for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
      //I want to skip a line with unicode character and continue next line
      if(line.toLowerCase().startsWith("\\u")){
            continue;
         //This is not working because i get the character itself and not the text 
        }
    }
}
```

**The text file**:

[image]

How to skip all the unicode characters while reading a file ?

Comment: Do you want to skip entire lines or just remove the unicode characters? Which characters do you want to keep, ASCII only?

Comment: _All_ characters you read in Unicode encoding are Unicode characters (apart from encoding errors, which are by definition not characters). Do you mean characters outside a certain other encoding? Or all non-printable characters? You will need to be more precise.

Comment: @Thomas I Want to skip the entire line, if the line contains an unicode character

Comment: If you are using any encoding which can encode Unicode (e.g. utf-8), every character is Unicode character. I guess you mean non ASCII when you say Unicode.

Comment: Well, the question would still be _what_ do you define as a unicode character. Basically every character is a unicode character but I assume you're refering to either non-ASCII or non-Latin-1 characters - which is it? In any case you could try to use a regex to check the line like `if(!line.matches("[whatever you want to allow]*")) { /*process*/ }`

Comment: @Thomas "every character is a unicode character" No, I said on purpose every character _that you can read under an Unicode encoding_ is a Unicode character. There's a bunch of characters that cannot be represented in Unicode, such as Rongorongo script (as of now). Unicode covers more and more characters all the time, but since new characters are being identified or created, impossible to cover them _all_. This should not take away from your other very valid points, though.

Comment: @Amadan I see and yes, I didn't think of new characters being created or "exotic" characters like Rongorongo (didn't even know that existed ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

You can skip all lines that contains non ASCII characters:

```
if(Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(line)){
    continue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All characters in a String are Unicode. A String is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units. By "Unicode", you must mean not also in some unspecified set of other character sets. For sake of argument, let's say ASCII.

A regular expression can *sometimes* be the simplest expression of a pattern requirement:

```
if (!line.matches("\\p{ASCII}*")) continue;
```

That is, if the string does not consist only of any number, including 0, (that's what `*` means) of "ASCII" characters, then continue.

(`String.matches` looks for a match on the whole string, so the actual regular expression pattern is `^\p{ASCII}*$`. )

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you going:

```
for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN) {
        // do something with this character
    }
}
```

You could use that as a starting point to either discard each non-basic character, or discard the entire line if it contains a single non-basic character.